# Need help on iterating over a mysql resultset in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have got 2 tables:

```
Institute:
-----------
id       name         city
-----    -------      -------
1        Name 1       London    
2        Name 2       Leeds
3        Name 3       Edinburgh

Course:
--------
id       i_id     name                      stream
-----    -----    --------------------      -------
1        1        Computer Engineering      Engineering 
2        1        Chemical Engineering      Engineering
3        2        Electronics Engineering   Engineering 
4        3        Mechanical Engineering    Engineering
```

I need following information in my resultset:

1. Institutes offering engineering courses(Name 1, Name 2, Name 3).
2. All the courses that the institute offers.

Now, this is my query to achieve this result set:

```
SELECT institute.id, institute.name AS i_name, institute.city, course.name AS c_name
FROM institute, course
WHERE institute.id = course.i_id
AND course.stream = 'Engineering'
ORDER BY institute.id
```

This query returns me 4 records:

```
id      i_name      city           c_name
---     -------     ---------      ----------------
1       Name 1      London         Computer Engineering
1       Name 1      London         Chemical Engineering
2       Name 2      Leeds          Electronics Engineering
3       Name 3      Edinburgh      Mechanical Engineering
```

How can I iterate over this resultset so that I get below list of data on web page:

```
 Found 3 Institutes
 ----------------------
 1) Name 1, London
    Courses Offered:-
    => Computer Engineering
    => Chemical Engineering

 2) Name 2, Leeds
    Courses Offered:-
    => Electronics Engineering

 3) Name 3, Edinburgh
    Courses Offered:-
    => Mechanical Engineering
```

[*ADDED*]

I have got pagination setup on my web page. Now let's say I want to display 2 records per page I will run the above query with `LIMIT 0,2`. Now obviously first 2 records in my query gives me same institute so in this case I would need third institute as well.

Can I make such a dynamic query?

Comment: Perhaps you could limit this question to the first point, and make another question later on covering the added point here? That would be easier since an answer has already been given on your first question.

Comment: In fact, you don't even have to wait for this question to have an answer before asking another one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$currentInstitute = null;
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
  if($row->i_name != $currentInstitute)
    echo $i++.") $row->i_name, $row->city\n   Courses offered:-\n";
  $currentInstitute = $row->i_name;
  echo "    => $row->c_name\n"; 
}
```